# How to release the retained objects or memory of app while logging out in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

I wanted to know that how we gonna release all the memory retained by the view controller in app while logging out.

I checked my app using instrument that the allocations were not released while logging out though i am on my logging screen.

as after using the app for a while the allocation shown by instruments goes to 10Mb but after logging out I am on login screen but the allocation are still the same i.e. 10MB.

I dont know how to modify that logout function so that i can clear the data retained by the other views..

Comment: It depends upon your logic and scenario. How do you present `LoginScreen`. Are you popping all your other screens, and did you properly released all the pointer in `dealloc`

Comment: If you are poping out a view controller from navigationController on logout action then please check if your dealloc method is being called or not ...If it is called then release all the properties and class variables there .

Comment: popping all other screen?? i need to check the dealloc of appdelegate class or all the view controller>???

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want to do is to create your own garbage collector.

Change your mindset.

What you need to be aiming for are: objects which release any memory they are retaining in their "dealloc" method.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to release every object you alloc, copy, mutableCopy, new or retain.
Also, use the Zombie tool in simulator to check for zombies (in addition to the Leaks and Allocations tools).

you say: "clear the data retained by the other views". But "the other views" should be clearing the data they retain.

Comment: zombie tool won't help you at all to find leaks, use the static analyzer. If fact zombies will make it so that nothing is ever released and any data you gather will be garbage.

Comment: For what it's worth I didn't say Zombie will help him find leaks but yes using Zombie tool may be of limited use in his scenario (I did say to use Leaks and Allocations tools also).

Comment: I didn't vote you down, just pointing out a possible red herring. Possibly saving op time.